# Calculations of the 80% of screen and 20% in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, size, cgsize

I write function that return size of the cell for the `UICollectionView`.

```
   fileprivate func getCellSize(with row: Int) -> CGSize {

        let percentage: CGFloat = row == 0 ? 0.8 : 0.2
        let width = self.collectionView?.frame.width
        let height = self.collectionView?.frame.height

        let expectedWidth = width! * percentage
        let expectedHeight = height! * 0.5

        return CGSize(width: expectedWidth, height: expectedHeight)
    }
```

This function is working fine but it has small issue that is connected with rounding it seams to me. Because layout that I receive is not fully covered with cells as it is expected.

The result of the function for the iPhone 6 emulator is following:

**0: ROW = (533.60000000000002,187.5)**

**1: ROW = (133.40000000000001,187.5)**

Actual result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: So what did you expect it to be and what actually happened here ?

Comment: This is obviously not the real code (percentage vs. peresenteg). Have you tried the debugger to find out which value is different from your expectation?

Comment: @Sandeep I add the screens.

Comment: You seem to have some section inset and some spacing in between cell, remove that it should be fine, it looks like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
if let frameWidth = self.collectionView?.frame.width {
     let row0Width = Int(Double(frameWidth) * 0.8)
     let otherWidth = frameWidth - row0Width
     let expectedWidth = row == 0 ? row0Width : otherWidth
     // ...
}
```

to avoid rounding issues?